# LINQ-to-SQL: Return an "array of rows" property (or column) per row

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq-to-sql

A simple query for `Groups` results in another query for every of its results:

```
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    db.Log = Console.Out;

    var query = from g in db.Groups
                let stats = from s in g.GroupCountryStats
                            select new
                            {
                                s.CountryId,
                                s.MembersCount
                            }
                select new
                {
                    g.ObjectId,
                    g.Name,
                    Stats = stats.ToArray()
                };

    var single = query.First(); // Take(2) would result in 2 extra calls, 3 in 3 and so on...
}
```

Console output (the Linq-to-Sql provider log):

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[ObjectId] AS [ObjectId], [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[Groups] AS [t0]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.3056.0

SELECT [t0].[CountryId] AS [CountryId], [t0].[MembersCount]
FROM [dbo].[GroupCountryStats] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[GroupId] = @x1
-- @x1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.7.3056.0

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would like to retrieve all the data in one query, instead of N+1 queries.

I tried using `DataLoadOptions`, with `LoadWith<Group>(T=>T.GroupCountryStats)` but the result is unchanged. The Linq2Sql still makes more than 1 call to the database.

How to avoid that and receive everything I need in a single call?

Comment: Instead of selecting a new object (stats) within your query, try joining the groups with group country stats.

Comment: @EricMagers `join` and `group by` also spawn multiple queries. Do you suggest not to group? Like, retrieve everything joined and groupby locally, in memory? But what if I need then several joins, like 5 or 10? For each `group`, I need an array of `GroupStats`, `GroupUserStats`, `GroupCountryStats`, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug (or a shortcoming at best) in LINQ-to-SQL. The query without `First` or `Take` translates into one decent SQL query containing an `OUTER JOIN`. But of course it'll give you *all* groups.

When LINQ-to-SQL is faced with statements that limit the number of results it seems to be programmed to apply these to the root entity only and then to query the adhering entities separately.

The funny thing is: this doesn't happen when `Skip` and `Take` are combined. So, as a hack, you could use `Skip(0).take(x)`, for example:

```
var results = query.Skip(0).Take(3).ToList();
```

If you need one result you have to do:

```
var results = query.Skip(0).Take(1).AsEnumerable().First();
```

Without `.AsEnumerable()` will again relapse into 1 + 1 queries. (I assume the SQL translation of `First` takes precedence in the query shape).

It's a dirty hack that's necessary to fight leaky abstractions of `IQueryable`. Make sure that, if you choose to use it, you comment it well in the code.

A final comment: maybe you should consider turning to a more advanced ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is the point when I should move on. Thank you.

Comment: But if I need more than one array-type property, it still must create a separate query, mustn't it?

Comment: It seems so, yes. As said, you better upgrade your technology, LINQ-to-SQL is not going to be improved any more and I wouldn't be surprised if one day it would disappear from later .Net releases.